# I need optimized toString() method of BigInteger

Tags: java, tostring, biginteger

I have a very large digit (the length number is 200000). And when i want to print this number

```
System.out.println(myBigInt);
```

a lot of time is spent on an implicit call method toString() of BigInteger number(about 5 sec)

Do you know any way how i can print biginteger on console? May be first need convert to byte array but i don't know what i do next.

I need print on console a very large biginteger number faster then

```
System.out.println(myBigInt);
```

Comment: It's quite possible that the delay is simply how long it takes to send 200000 characters to the console, rather than the actual conversion to a string.

Comment: I'm guessing that it would be pretty hard to do significantly better than the Java library designers... Especially since you don't have direct access to the array that backs the `BigInteger`

Comment: What is the question? What have you tried? Are you sure (via a profiler) that the `.toString()` call is what is the main slowpoke here and not the `System.out.println()` call? Printing is _very_ costly. Why do you need all the digits, anyway? Would printing it to a file be okay? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: i need override method toString() for biginteger

Answer (score 1):

By default, System.out.print() is only line-buffered and does a lot work related to Unicode handling. Because of its small buffer size, System.out.println() is not well suited to handle many repetitive outputs in a batch mode. Each line is flushed right away. If your output is mainly ASCII-based then by removing the Unicode-related activities, the overall execution time will be better.

you can use the following to increase the speed.

```
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new
                     FileOutputStream(java.io.FileDescriptor.out), "ASCII"), 512);
out.write(String.valueOf(myBigInt));
```

Comment: String.valueOf(myBigInt) -> implicit call toString()

Comment: String.valueOf(myBigInt)  returns the the string representation of the argument.  toString() returns a String object representing the specified myBigInt.